# The semi-empirical formula and $E=mc^2$

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

The semi-empirical formula is used to find the binding energy of a nucleus. 
But if you know the mass of a nucleus and the number of neutrons and protons that this nucleus consists of (and you know the mass of a neutron and a proton), then you can calculate the binding energy using $E=mc^2$.
What is the difference between these two procedures, and do you get the same energy either way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semi-empirical mass formula is derived from a *fit* to the measured masses. If you know the numbers of protons and neutrons then the idea is that the SEMF should give you a good estimate of that mass (there are of course small residuals  of the order 0.2 MeV to the fit).

$$M(A,Z)c^2 = (A-Z)m_n c^2 + Zm_pc^2 - AE_b,$$
where $A,Z$ are the mass number and atomic number and $E_b$ is the binding energy per nucleon that is described by the SEMF. So of course if you can measure the mass $M$, then you could easily rearrange this formula to give $E_b$. However, the beauty of the SEMF is it gives a very simple way to attempt to *understand* what is happening to the binding energy as you change the number of nucleons and the neutron/proton ratio. It also allows you to predict the properties of exotic or short-lived nuclei (for example in the crusts of neutron stars), where you may not have the luxury of a laboratory-based measurement.

In direct response to your question. Yes you can do this and the answers should be very similar. But there are small differences because the SEMF is just a model, and a relatively simple one at that. For instance if you were thinking of the Weizsacker liquid-drop version, then this doesn't predict the larger binding energies of the "magic number" nuclei, that are better describe by the shell model.

Answer (score 2):

The semi-empirical mass formula (SEMF) is much more involved than this, and tries to take into account various other factors that will affect the mass/energy of the nucleus. For any nucleus, of course if you KNOW its mass beforehand then simply subtracting the individual masses of protons and neutrons will give you ($\pm$)the binding energy, but the SEMF at least tries to be more *predictive*. Some of the things it takes into account are repulsions, nuclear surface tensions, volume effects and asymmetry due to the exclusion principle.